# How to avoid concurrent clicks on navigation items

Tags: android

I am Calling Same activity for different navigation items depend on Requirement. My question is how to avoid concurrent clicks of same navigation item based on id. If I set Flags remaining items which are call to that same activity are also not working please help me out.

Code

```
if (id == R.id.nav_Issue_Based) { 
try { String fileName = "assessments.pdf"; 
      viewPdfActivity(fileName, "Issue Based");
      drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START); 
 } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); } }
```

another

```
private void viewPdfActivity(String fileName, String title) { 
try { 
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
bundle.putSerializable("file_name", fileName);
b undle.putString("title", title); 
startActivity(context, bundle, DocumentsLoaderActivity.class); 
} 
catch (Exception e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); } 
}
```

more code

```
private void startActivity(Context context, Bundle b, Class<?> cls) { 
try { 
Intent intent = new Intent(context, cls); 
if (b != null) { 
  intent.putExtras(b); 
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION); 
} 
context.startActivity(intent); 
} catch (Exception e) { 
  e.printStackTrace(); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please put some code here

Comment: if (id == R.id.nav_Issue_Based) {
                try {
                    String fileName = "assessments.pdf";
                    viewPdfActivity(fileName, "Issue Based");
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

Comment: private void viewPdfActivity(String fileName, String title) {
        try {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("file_name", fileName);
            bundle.putString("title", title);
            startActivity(context, bundle, DocumentsLoaderActivity.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Comment: private void startActivity(Context context, Bundle b, Class<?> cls) {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, cls);
            if (b != null) {
                intent.putExtras(b);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            }

            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Set your activity on with you are navigating, single instance in `Manifest` as: **launchMode="singleInstance"**. It will open only for the last click.

Comment: If I set launchmode= singleInstance for my activity I am unable to click on other navigation item to open the same activity why because I am using same activity for 4 navigation items to open it but not same item to load twice

Comment: when your activity is single instance and launched with different data from different place then when you try to reopen it onNewIntent() is called. So you can update your content here

Answer (score 0):

try this use `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeScreenActivity.class);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(intent);
```

**or this in manifest file declare your activity like this**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

for more information [read docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: inflating of same screen visible to our eyes If I don't want that What should I do is there any solution?

Comment: didn't get you can you explain in brief